# Create pop-up window from email link without using custom javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, popup

I am sending an email that includes a link.  When the recipient clicks that link, I'd like the resulting page to come up pop-up (rather than open in a new tab) when clicked.

I'm using Gmail as my reference mail client.

Things I've tried:

- `target="_blank"`: opens in a new tab, not a pop-up
- `<a onclick="window.open(...)">`: stripped out by gmail.
- `<a href="javascript:window.open(...)">`: stripped out by gmail.
- opening a new tab, and then generating a pop-up from that tab via `onLoad` or similar: pop-up blocked.

Most popup-related online resources I've found so far have been quite out of date, but the rule of thumb appears to be "[if an event is
user-initiated, it will be allowed to open a popup](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/155463-how-get-around-popup-blockers)."

Even a partial solution (only works in Chrome/Firefox/Safari/etc) would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all mail clients strip out inline JavaScript because it is vector for malware.

You can only include regular links in Emails.

Comment: Thanks! I figured as much.